# protobuf UnusedPrivateParameter compilation error

Tags: java, proto

I am using the proto file to generate a Java file but I'm getting an `UnusedPrivateParameter` compilation error.
error log
cannot find symbol
symbol:   class UnusedPrivateParameter
location: class com.TransactionEventOuterClass.TransactionEvent
[ERROR] /D:/com/TransactionEventOuterClass.java:[31653,9] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class UnusedPrivateParameter
location: class com..TransactionEventOuterClass.Details
[INFO] 22 errors

-- java file error

```
@java.lang.Override
@SuppressWarnings({"unused"})
protected java.lang.Object newInstance(
    UnusedPrivateParameter unused) {
  return new TransactionEvent();
}
```

jdk version - 1.8
intellij version - 2017.3.7
protoc compiler version- 3.11.4

I am using the following dependency and plugin :

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
        <artifactId>protoc-jar</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.4</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

<plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
                <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.4</version>
                <executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question and show the _full_ error message.

Comment: That class is part of GeneratedMessageV3, which I'd expect your class to be a subclass of.